# Apache2 "You don't have permission to access / on this server"

Tags: apache, apache2

Cannot access document root folder files - get this error:

```
You don't have permission to access / on this server.
```

**Apache version**

```
Server version: Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)
```

**Virtual Host Configuration**
Inside sites-available

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName site1

        ServerAlias www.site1


        RailsEnv production
        RackEnv production


        DocumentRoot /var/www/site1/webservices/public

        <Directory "/var/www/site/webservices/public">
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
                Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
        </Directory>


</VirtualHost>
```

Inside apache2/hosts file added

```
127.0.0.1 site1
```

Restarted Apache2

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Can it be a permission issue?

Comment: Check the permissions of the document root folder in the filesystem. Maybe, apache does not have permission to traverse and or read the document root folder. Use `ls -l`

Comment: Tried giving full access drwxrwsrwx recursively to all subfoldes within it yet the same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to tell Apache what to do with folders (as `/` is a folder). You need to tell Apache what file should be used to list the folder content.

Try to set:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html
```

Now for ruby I'm not sure, but maybe you forgot the index.html file?

On the Options settings you could add Indexes, and remove Multiviews in case of, as Multiviews try to guess the file to use and this makes things harder usually. So using something like:

```
Options FollowSymLinks Indexes -Multiviews
```

Comment: Thanks for a clear response. Appreciate it! The issue was due to another virtual host configuration with same site name and different document root which was taking a precedence.

Comment: random: ok, you should put the real answer there and check it as an answer, to remove this from opened questions and to help users facing same problems.